# JQUERY for loop not outputting integers within the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I tried this code below but the logged output of the loop is coming up as `3649` which are not id numbers in the array being passed. Even when adding more ids or subtracting ids from the array, it does not change the output of the ajax code.

I have confirmed the array is being received properly by the function below by using a `console.log(id)`. This verifies the output as below:

The array as being passed:

```
 console.log(cids);
(3) […]
​
0: "45"
​
1: "47"
​
2: "46"
​
length: 3
```

What might I be doing wrong?

```
function func2(cids) {
    console.log(cids);
      for(let id of cids)
        var parent = document.getElementById('mydiv_' + id)
        console.log(id);
      }
}
```

If I `console.log(id);` I get 3649 which isn't even in the array

Comment: It doesn't seem like there is enough of the code provided to help troubleshoot this, but I'd recommend reducing the problem down to help isolate it.  For example, maybe bypass the ajax call and hard code the a variable of cids that you can pass to callD().  Once you've determined that there is/isn't a problem with that function, you can incorporate the ajax portion back in and see if you still get the expected results.

Comment: @chrissmith thanks . This is the only code for this that I have. As mentioned in the OP I have already verified that the array is making it to the second function properly so I dont know what else to do. I did just edit the code to make it even less though

Comment: What is in the variable exactly.... `console.log(JSON.stringify(cids));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a curly brace. Try:

```
function func2(cids) {
    console.log(cids);
    for(let id of cids){ //this one is missing
        var parent = document.getElementById('mydiv_' + id)
        console.log(id);
    }
}
```